# How to use like the useSelector in Class Component like mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

How to use like the useSelector in a Class Component with `find` the id of data.
I know `mapStateToProps` can be use here, but I don't know how to work with React Navigation. Passing props from other component and getting the props then use it just like above the code.

The `props.navigation.getParam` is from React Navigation and my other Class Component

In Function Component, I use useSelector. Like this code:

```
const productId = props.navigation.getParam('productId');
const selectedProduct = useSelector(state => 
    state.products.availableProducts.find(prod => prod.id == productId)
);
```

My question is how will I convert this to be work in Class Component?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use useSelector in class based component only in functional component